# Is it possible to use VirtualStringTree for a master detail grid view?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

Alright I got something really tricky here...
I would like to DRAW/USE Headers to a ChildNode.
I think the idea is reasonable because it would look amazing to have headers in subnodes so the childnodes can be specified in a table. 
Is there a feature that VST has or is it not possible at all?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Last time I investigated such an idea, I ended up abandoning using VirtualTreeView for it at all, and used something like Express Quantum Grid from Developer Express, which has such capabilities built in.  It's sort of more a grid inside a grid (nesting grids) than a tree-view at that point.

Comment: @Warren, your point about *grid inside a grid* brought me a crazy idea, create a nested virtual tree view inside of a virtual tree view and control its visibility on collapse and expand node events. This would be definitely easier to implement than simulating it.

Comment: Not impossible as well as not so easy. Even using nested virtual tree view is not so simple.

Comment: Well if you guys have any ideas or a small snippet that would be great.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***1. Is there a way to use VirtualTreeView for a master / detail grid view ?***

No, there is no such feature available at this time and IMHO won't be, since that would involve a very big intervention to an existing code.

***2. How to create fully functional header for a child node detail grid view ?***

Considering few ways, how to simulate header look and behavior for child nodes I've found useful to use nested tree views for a detail grid view. This brings you the separateness for your detail data and allows you to minimize the whole simulation to positioning of the nested tree view into a child node's rectangle.

***2.1. Startup project***

In the following project I'm trying to show how complicated could be implement such an easy task like the positioning of a control inside of a child node could be (without involving the original VirtualTree code). Take it just as a startup project, not as a final solution.

***2.2. Known issues & limitations:***

- this project was written and tested to use only one child per root node, so don't be surprised with a behavior when you exceed this limit, because this was not designed nor even tested for
- when a double click column resize of a main tree animates the column resize, the nested tree views are overdrawn with lines when the canvas is being scrolled by the ScrollDC function
- to keep the VirtualTree code without changing I've overrided the method for scroll bars updating. It is used to update nested tree views bounds whenever the scrollbars needs to be updated
- current `OnExpanded` implementation fires the event before the range and scroll positions are fixed, what makes the code more complicated and with a big weakness - the bounds of a detail tree view are updated after the tree is shown, what can be sometimes visible

***2.3. Project code***

It was written and tested in Delphi 2009 with respect to use in Delphi 7. For commented version of a next code [`follow this link`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12188882/1):

***Unit1.pas***

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, VirtualTrees;

type
  TVTScrollBarsUpdateEvent = procedure(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; DoRepaint: Boolean) of object;
  TVirtualStringTree = class(VirtualTrees.TVirtualStringTree)
  private
    FOnUpdateScrollBars: TVTScrollBarsUpdateEvent;
  public
    procedure UpdateScrollBars(DoRepaint: Boolean); override;
  published
    property OnUpdateScrollBars: TVTScrollBarsUpdateEvent read FOnUpdateScrollBars write FOnUpdateScrollBars;
  end;

type
  PNodeSubTree = ^TNodeSubTree;
  TNodeSubTree = class
    FChildTree: TVirtualStringTree;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    VirtualStringTree1: TVirtualStringTree;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure VirtualStringTree1AfterAutoFitColumns(Sender: TVTHeader);
    procedure VirtualStringTree1BeforeDrawTreeLine(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
      Node: PVirtualNode; Level: Integer; var PosX: Integer);
    procedure VirtualStringTree1Collapsed(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
      Node: PVirtualNode);
    procedure VirtualStringTree1ColumnResize(Sender: TVTHeader;
      Column: TColumnIndex);
    procedure VirtualStringTree1Expanded(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
      Node: PVirtualNode);
    procedure VirtualStringTree1FocusChanging(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; OldNode,
      NewNode: PVirtualNode; OldColumn, NewColumn: TColumnIndex;
      var Allowed: Boolean);
    procedure VirtualStringTree1FreeNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
      Node: PVirtualNode);
    procedure VirtualStringTree1MeasureItem(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
      TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; var NodeHeight: Integer);
  private
    procedure InvalidateSubTrees(Tree: TBaseVirtualTree);
    procedure ResizeSubTrees(Tree: TBaseVirtualTree);
    procedure UpdateSubTreeBounds(Tree: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
    procedure OnUpdateScrollBars(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; DoRepaint: Boolean);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TVirtualStringTree }

procedure TVirtualStringTree.UpdateScrollBars(DoRepaint: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
  if HandleAllocated and Assigned(FOnUpdateScrollBars) then
    FOnUpdateScrollBars(Self, DoRepaint);
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  VirtualStringTree1.NodeDataSize := SizeOf(TNodeSubTree);
  VirtualStringTree1.OnUpdateScrollBars := OnUpdateScrollBars;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: PNodeSubTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode;
begin
  Node := VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(nil);
  Node := VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(Node);
  VirtualStringTree1.InitNode(Node);
  Data := VirtualStringTree1.GetNodeData(Node);
  Data^ := TNodeSubTree.Create;
  Data^.FChildTree := TVirtualStringTree.Create(nil);
  with Data.FChildTree do
  begin
    Visible := False;
    Parent := VirtualStringTree1;
    Height := 150;
    DefaultNodeHeight := 21;
    Header.AutoSizeIndex := 0;
    Header.Font.Charset := DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    Header.Font.Color := clWindowText;
    Header.Font.Height := -11;
    Header.Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    Header.Font.Style := [];
    Header.Height := 21;
    Header.Options := [hoColumnResize, hoDrag, hoShowSortGlyphs, hoVisible];
    TabStop := False;
    with Header.Columns.Add do
    begin
      Width := 100;
      Text := 'Header item 1';
    end;
    with Header.Columns.Add do
    begin
      Width := 100;
      Text := 'Header item 2';
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1AfterAutoFitColumns(Sender: TVTHeader);
begin
  InvalidateSubTrees(Sender.Treeview);
end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1BeforeDrawTreeLine(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Level: Integer; var PosX: Integer);
begin
  if Level = 1 then
    PosX := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1Collapsed(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  Data: PNodeSubTree;
begin
  Data := VirtualStringTree1.GetNodeData(Node.FirstChild);
  if Assigned(Data^) and Assigned(Data^.FChildTree) then
    Data^.FChildTree.Visible := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1ColumnResize(Sender: TVTHeader;
  Column: TColumnIndex);
begin
  ResizeSubTrees(Sender.Treeview);
end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1Expanded(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  Data: PNodeSubTree;
begin
  Data := VirtualStringTree1.GetNodeData(Node.FirstChild);
  if Assigned(Data^) and Assigned(Data^.FChildTree) then
    Data^.FChildTree.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1FocusChanging(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  OldNode, NewNode: PVirtualNode; OldColumn, NewColumn: TColumnIndex;
  var Allowed: Boolean);
begin
  if Sender.GetNodeLevel(NewNode) = 1 then
  begin
    Allowed := False;
    if Sender.AbsoluteIndex(OldNode) > Sender.AbsoluteIndex(NewNode) then
      Sender.FocusedNode := Sender.GetPreviousSibling(OldNode)
    else
    if OldNode <> Sender.GetLastChild(nil) then
      Sender.FocusedNode := Sender.GetNextSibling(OldNode)
    else
      Sender.FocusedNode := OldNode;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1FreeNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  Data: PNodeSubTree;
begin
  Data := VirtualStringTree1.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Assigned(Data^) then
  begin
    if Assigned(Data^.FChildTree) then
      Data^.FChildTree.Free;
    Data^.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1MeasureItem(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; var NodeHeight: Integer);
var
  Data: PNodeSubTree;
begin
  if VirtualStringTree1.GetNodeLevel(Node) = 1 then
  begin
    Data := VirtualStringTree1.GetNodeData(Node);
    if Assigned(Data^) and Assigned(Data^.FChildTree) then
      NodeHeight := Data^.FChildTree.Height + 8;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.InvalidateSubTrees(Tree: TBaseVirtualTree);
var
  Data: PNodeSubTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode;
begin
  Node := Tree.GetFirst;
  while Assigned(Node) do
  begin
    if Tree.HasChildren[Node] then
    begin
      Data := Tree.GetNodeData(Node.FirstChild);
      if Assigned(Data^) and Assigned(Data^.FChildTree) then
      begin
        Data^.FChildTree.Header.Invalidate(nil);
        Data^.FChildTree.Invalidate;
      end;
    end;
    Node := Tree.GetNextSibling(Node);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ResizeSubTrees(Tree: TBaseVirtualTree);
var
  Node: PVirtualNode;
begin
  Node := Tree.GetFirst;
  while Assigned(Node) do
  begin
    if Tree.HasChildren[Node] then
      UpdateSubTreeBounds(Tree, Node.FirstChild);
    Node := Tree.GetNextSibling(Node);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateSubTreeBounds(Tree: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  R: TRect;
  Data: PNodeSubTree;
begin
  if Assigned(Node) then
  begin
    Data := Tree.GetNodeData(Node);
    if Assigned(Data^) and Assigned(Data^.FChildTree) and
      Data^.FChildTree.Visible then
    begin
      R := Tree.GetDisplayRect(Node, -1, False, True);
      R.Left := R.Left + (Tree as TVirtualStringTree).Indent;
      R.Top := R.Top + 4;
      R.Right := R.Right - 8;
      R.Bottom := R.Bottom - 4;
      Data^.FChildTree.BoundsRect := R;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnUpdateScrollBars(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; DoRepaint: Boolean);
begin
  ResizeSubTrees(Sender);
end;

end.
```

***Unit1.dfm***

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 282
  ClientWidth = 468
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignSize = (
    468
    282)
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object VirtualStringTree1: TVirtualStringTree
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 371
    Height = 266
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]
    Header.AutoSizeIndex = 0
    Header.Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Header.Font.Color = clWindowText
    Header.Font.Height = -11
    Header.Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
    Header.Font.Style = []
    Header.Height = 21
    Header.Options = [hoColumnResize, hoDblClickResize, hoDrag, hoShowSortGlyphs, hoVisible]
    TabOrder = 0
    TreeOptions.MiscOptions = [toVariableNodeHeight]
    OnAfterAutoFitColumns = VirtualStringTree1AfterAutoFitColumns
    OnBeforeDrawTreeLine = VirtualStringTree1BeforeDrawTreeLine
    OnCollapsed = VirtualStringTree1Collapsed
    OnColumnResize = VirtualStringTree1ColumnResize
    OnExpanded = VirtualStringTree1Expanded
    OnFocusChanging = VirtualStringTree1FocusChanging
    OnFreeNode = VirtualStringTree1FreeNode
    OnMeasureItem = VirtualStringTree1MeasureItem
    ExplicitWidth = 581
    ExplicitHeight = 326
    Columns = <
      item
        Position = 0
        Width = 75
        WideText = 'Column 1'
      end
      item
        Position = 1
        Width = 75
        WideText = 'Column 2'
      end
      item
        Position = 2
        Width = 75
        WideText = 'Column 3'
      end>
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 385
    Top = 8
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Anchors = [akTop, akRight]
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
    ExplicitLeft = 595
  end
end
```

***2.4. Screenshot***

[image]

Comment: This is the most impressive code I have ever seen in my life! Wish I could give you more rep points for this!

Comment: toVariableNodeHeight is missing in TreeOptions.MiscOptions, this is needed for this sample project, otherwise the OnMeasureItem is not called.

Comment: @Joachim, thanks for the hint! I'm fairly sure I copied the project as it was at the time when I took the screenshot, so it might be just some older version of VT that fired the `OnMeasureItem` event even without this option included in the `MiscOptions` set. Unfortunately I didn't mention which version I used that time to verify.

Comment: You are right, older version fired the event always, which did not make too much sense if other parts of the code did not expect non-variable node heights due to a missing toVariableNodeHeight flag.